# iOS app deep linking: Return to previous app or access current url scheme of current app

Tags: ios, swift, deep-linking, url-scheme, custom-keyboard

I'm developing a custom keyboard for iOS. When I'm e.g. in Safari using my custom keyboard, I have a button in my keyboard to jump to to keyboard containing app. Then in my keyboard app I have the iOS specific "<- Safari" button in the top left corner to jump back to Safari.

Is it possible to programmatically jump back to the source application (in my example Safari)?

Or can I send the original url scheme to my containing app and then open the previous app (could be ANY) by the url scheme?

It must be somehow possible, because the app Scandit Wedge does exactly what I want. I created an empty test app without any url scheme and with the Scandit Wedge keyboard I can go to Scandit app, read barcode and it goes automatically back to the source app.

Here's a video I recorded:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UiHH4NanlkA

Comment: Your video link is not working anymore...
Though I think I know what you mean, because the App "ScanKey" does the same.
But it seems, that "ScanKey" does NOT use an URL scheme to open it's containing app because there is no "<- Safari" or similar back button when the containing app is opened.
Did you find a solution to this problem??

Comment: Have you solved this challenge? :)

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you have to implement inter-app two way communication using **`x-callback-url`**. x-callback is just a "protocol" to format the `NSURL` to ease the data processing at the receiver end and also allowed the source app to receive the correct callback function. You can explore more this with [evernote](https://github.com/evernote/evernote-ios-x-callback-url) and [this](http://x-callback-url.com/examples/) tutorial.

Comment: This answer is unfortunately not helpful, because it requires special implementation in the source app. In my case for a 3rd party custom keyboard it can by used in ANY kind of app.